# Should JWT be a separate auth micro-service and not sit with the backend business logic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, microservices

I am new to the micro-services architecture , I am building application using SpringBoot and wanted to add JWT auth for my APIs .

Ref link : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world

I was wondering if I should separate out the authentication / authorization code from the business-micro-service(BMS) . So each time a rest API call to BMS would in turn call the auth-microservice for validation . Would this be a good practice or would it be a lot on the network traffic ?

Calls might look like :

Client -> BusinessApp -> AuthMS -> Business App -> Client

The reason of separating it out is that there is some configuration and code that would not look good coupled with business app , but I am unsure of the network cost it would take for each API call.

Example code in JWT app which would make sense to be in different service / server running ? :

```
import java.util.Objects;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.javainuse.service.JwtUserDetailsService;
import com.javainuse.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.javainuse.model.JwtRequest;
import com.javainuse.model.JwtResponse;
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
@Autowired
private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
}
private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
try {
authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
} catch (DisabledException e) {
throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
} catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to let your api gateway handle all the authorization requests.
The request will pass through the api gateway where it will be validated and only then have access to the micro-service (where the business logic is there). Let your gateway take care of the following:

> (1) validate tokens with every request
>   (2) prevent all unauthenticated requests to the services

[Check this out for more details](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-part-3-fafc9d7187e8)

Comment: So I believe its a good practise to separate it out as a micro service , but i have a doubt , how does gateway get to know about the incoming request given that its running as a different micro service on different port

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-api-gateway-zuul/ This link has it all

Comment: I've tried same example as in spring cloud api gateway zuul link , but my request is failing with 401 , unauthorized ,, any idea ?  I am just trying a basic example of zuul with springboot to understand the routing to other services through gateway , thanks

Comment: was stuck for 3 days , tried everything , fixed it by cleaning the project .